# WordPress Plugins not working - Jquery showing errors

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm new to the development world and I started by migrating an Html web site to WordPress theme using a backbone theme.

Everything looks good on the website (on localhost & live) but not on my plugins dashboard & tools.

When I enter some pages of the plugin (for example I wanted to create a form using Ninja form, but the page doesn't show properly), the console start throwing some JQuery/Js errors. (picture below) 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p6EL.png)

Here's an example of the error : "at n.onRender (builder,js?ver=2.9.8:7)

```
onRender: function() {
        this.$el = this.$el.children(),
        this.$el.unwrap(),
        this.setElement(this.$el),
        this.itemControls.show(new e({
            model: this.model
        })),
        jQuery(this.el).disableSelection(),
        i.channel("app").request("is:mobile") && jQuery(this.el).on("taphold", function(e, t) {
            jQuery(e.target).hasClass("nf-edit-settings") || (jQuery(this).addClass("ui-sortable-helper drag-selected"),
            jQuery(this).ClassyWiggle("start", {
                degrees: [".65", "1", ".65", "0", "-.65", "-1", "-.65", "0"],
                delay: 50
            }))
        })
    },
```

Any Idea guys what is causing the problem ?

Comment: Maybe jQuery UI is not properly loading.

Comment: @Michael how can I check that ?